# django find in field type json with value type int or str

Tags: django, django-models

I have a field type Json in a model, but I can't be sure if it's an integer or a string, the long version that works is:

```
cars = Car.objects.filter(
   user_id=self.user_id,
   car_type=self.car_type,
   facture__facture_id=1,
)
if len(cars) == 0:
    cars = Car.objects.filter(
       user_id=self.user_id,
       car_type=self.car_type,
       facture__facture_id=1,
    )
```

But I want to do not repeat all the block, and I want to know if there is another way like:

```
Car.objects.filter(
   user_id=self.user_id,
   car_type=self.car_type,
   facture__facture_id=1 | facture__facture_id='1',
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) for "OR" logic ( with `|` operator) ([also here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q))

Something like

```
cars = Car.objects.filter(
   user_id=self.user_id,
   car_type=self.car_type,
).filter( 
   Q( facture__facture_id=1 ) | Q( facture__facture_id='1' ) 
)
```

(except I am unsure how this uncertainty can arise. Is it a CharField or an IntegerField? I can understand needing to use Q to deal with variants of a CharField).

You can also greatly reduce duplicated code by generating one queryset from another:

```
cars_base_qs = Car.objects.filter(
    user_id=self.user_id,
    car_type=self.car_type )
...
cars = cars_base_qs.filter( ...)
```